# Shortcut to switch windows, bringing the newly active window to the top

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

"Command-Tab" switches between browser (or other) windows, but leaves the newly active window underneath, where you can't see it. What good is that?

This such an essential, minute-to-minute maneuver that there MUST be a shortcut that switches to another window and brings it to the top (as PCs do). Isn't there such a shortcut?

I think this question has been asked before, but I've never seen a straightforward solution. I'd like to make sure that the answer really is "You can't do that."

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, when you say *"but leaves the newly active window underneath"* - this is not normal behaviour. Is this something that's always happening for you? Or just with some apps/windows?

Answer (score 1):

⌘ + TAB switches between applications. It brings up last active window of selected application.

Application can have many windows open (or no open window at all). To navigate between application windows:

- first navigate to desired application using ⌘ + TAB
- without releasing ⌘ use Up or Down arrow on keyboard to see all open windows of selected application.
- Use Up/Down/Left/Right arrows to navigate between windows.
- reaching desired window press Enter to bring it in front

Comment: I want to navigate between open windows, not necessarily between apps. E.g., on my Google Chrome browser I can open a new Google Chrome browser window. But when I try to switch between them, command+tab makes the switch but does not bring the newly active Google Chrome window to the top. I have to mouse and click on it to get it on top. This was a no-brainer on my PC, so I must be doing something wrong on my Mac.