# How to change new window coordinates?

Tags: window-manager

I would like to reset new window coordinates: now when I open new Opera window - it is placed just below the main opera window while I'd like it to hide the main window completely at least at the top. It is very annoying as any mouse slips above this second window cause window switch and change the focus to the main opera window. I do not know if this switching is a bug or normal behaviour but I found it extremely annoying.

[image]

Comment: It’s a little difficult to follow  Could you [edit] with some clarifications as to “main window” (is it Opera or something else?) and what exactly you’re trying to solve.  Also, be certain to indicate what version macOS and Opera you’re using.

Comment: plz look at the picture - you see active window and inactive behind it. if i just move a mouse above the top border of this active window (the cursor comes above inactive window) - the window which was behind come forward and obscures the window which is lower. I want any new window to appear at the same coordinates as the window which invoked it via File->New Window.

Comment: Wouldn't maximizing the window be enough?

Comment: There are shortcuts to cycle through all windows of an App.  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372901/119271 for details.

Comment: no, done it - too annoying, I want the new window to appear at the same location as the parent.

Comment: I doubt there's a setting for that.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

Finder->Go->GotoFolder paste

> ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist

Delete the file located.
Restart.
Now Opera's File->New window opens with the same coordinates as the parent (main) window, a "new private window" does the same.